# Targeting Custom Property with Multi Bindings in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, multibinding

I'm trying to use WPF MultiBinding to target a custom property I defined on my UserControl.  I'm not having any luck.  All of the examples that I've seen target built-in .Net properties (Text, ItemSource, IsEnabled).  I'm wondering if you can target a custom property.  Please help.

```
///
public partial class ActivityStatusDisplay : UserControl
{


    public ActivityStatusDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value for the read/write property named 
    /// Status. 
    ///  
    /// </summary>
    public TaskStatuses Status
    {
        get
        {
            return (TaskStatuses)GetValue(StatusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StatusProperty, value);

            UpdateForStatus(value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.
        Register("Status", typeof(TaskStatuses), typeof(ActivityStatusDisplay), null);
```

with the XAML for binding looking like one of these:

```
<my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PatientTaskCollection}">
                    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto">
                            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <my1:ActivityStatusDisplay Margin="3">
                                        <mb:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
                                            <mb:MultiBindings>
                                                <mb:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Status" Converter="{StaticResource StatusConverter}">
                                                    <mb:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                        <mb:BindingCollection>
                                                            <Binding Path="RecoveryTaskStatusID"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="Due"/>
                                                        </mb:BindingCollection>
                                                    </mb:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                </mb:MultiBinding>
                                            </mb:MultiBindings>
                                        </mb:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
                                    </my1:ActivityStatusDisplay>
```

or something like:

```
<my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PatientTaskCollection}">
                        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto">
                                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <my1:ActivityStatusDisplay Margin="3">
                                            <my1:ActivityStatusDisplay.Status>
                                             <mb:MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StatusConverter}">
                                                                <Binding Path="RecoveryTaskStatusID"/>
                                                                <Binding Path="Due"/>

                                                    </mb:MultiBinding>
                                            </my1:ActivityStatusDisplay.Status>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you are assuming the "setter" method for the `Status` property gets called when the binding changes its value.  This is doesn't happen.  Binding calls the `SetValue` method directly.  Hence your call to `UpdateForStatus` doesn't occur when value is modified as a result of binding.

Here is how your dependency property should look, (I'll assume `TaskStatuses` is an enum type)

```
public TaskStatuses Status
{
    get { return (TaskStatuses)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Status", 
    typeof(TaskStatuses), 
    typeof(ActivityStatusDisplay),
    new PropertyMetaData(TaskStatuses.Default, OnStatusPropertyChanged));

private static void OnStatusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ActivityStatusDisplay source = (ActivityStatusDisplay)d;
   TaskStatuses value = (TaskStatuses)e.NewValue;
   source.UpdateForStatus(value);
}
```

Using the `PropertyMetaData` parameter of the `Register` method we can specify the default value this property should have and a static callback method to call whenever the value of the dependency property is changed.  Its from this callback method that you would want to call your `UpdateForStatus` method.

Comment: So giddy right now ... that worked.  I'll be sure to send you royalties for any money we make off this thing.  Thank you so, so much.

Comment: I tried to "vote up" your answer, but I'm too much of a noob to do it.

Comment: @Mark: Glad it helped, money not necessary.  Clicking the great big tick next to this answer would suffice.